# Set Style and Disable Focus for ALL AS3 TextInput Components?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

How to "setStyle" and "disable focus" (remove the default blue line rectangle when focus) for "ALL" AS3 TextInput components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you plan to somehow keep a record of them, I think the best way would probably be to recurse the display list looking for instances of that class. Something like:

```
// Necessary imports
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import fl.controls.TextInput;


function disableAllInputs(container : DisplayObjectContainer) : void
{
    var i : uint;
    for (i=0; i<container.numChildren; i++) {
        var child : DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);
        if (child is TextInput) {                       // Proper class here
           var input : TextInput = TextInput(child);    // and here
           // Disable focus and setStyle here
        }
        else if (child is DisplayObjectContainer) {
           // Recurse
           disableAllInputs(child as DisplayObjectContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through all the children of the supplied container and check if they are inputs. If they are, you can execute the desired code for them in the appropriate if statement. If however they are other containers, it will recurse and loop through the children of that container too.

I'm not sure what the class name is of the text input component, but I think it's simply `TextInput`. If not, just replace with the proper name where marked in the above source code.

Comment: Flash returns error when I try to implement this code. It cannot access the TextInputs. Is there something easier like "TextInput.prototype"?

Comment: What is the error that it returns? If you specify the error it's most likely an easy fix. Did you import the fl.controls.TextInput class?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I couldn't browse for 2 days. I forgot about the error, I think it was about Flash couldn't find the Display Object instances. I didn't import the "fl.controls.TextInput" Class, because I drag the component from the Components box. Never mind, I used "for loop" to style and disable focus rect of all TextInputs. This way is troublesome, because I had to add it in every MovieClip that contains TextInputs. So it would be better if I can style all TextInputs by using "prototype" property. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: My solution above is a variation of the loop you have likely created yourself, but it recurses, meaning that it will go through all movie clips on the display list. If you try my code and tell me the error, I can likely help you to get it to work. I will edit my code so that you know what to import.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally I know what to fix. Now it is working, and I can disable all focus rect of the TextInputs.